# How to Use .htaccess to 301 Redirect to Another Url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

So say I have a website mysite.com/websites

How can I redirect to these urls.

`mysite.com/websites?url=http://google.com` to `http://google.com`

or

`mysite.com/websites?url=http://yahoo.com` to `http://yahoo.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^websites/?$ %1? [NC,R=301,L]
```